# How will a web application with XHTML 1.1 and frames behave on major browsers?

Tags: cross-browser, xhtml, frames

I am working on a web application which was built on XHTML 1.1 and also uses frameset and frames. Now the application runs only on IE (upto IE 8). I am trying to make changes so that it runs on major browsers. I have following questions:

1. Is XHTML 1.1 supported on major browsers and is it according to W3C standards?
2. I read that frames are obsolete in HTML5 but if I use XHTML 1.1 then are frames going to work in all browsers?
3. Is there any change in XHTML since XHTML 1.1 which I should incorporate?

Comment: Yes, yes, and XHTML5.

Comment: I am trying to make the application w3c compliant and compatible with all browsers.Is using XHTML 1.1 recommended or I should convert to XHTML5.

Comment: You should probably convert to the HTML syntax of HTML5, not the XHTML syntax of HTML5. If you say it only ran on older versions of IE, you weren't really using XHTML 1.1 anyway. If you don't understand that, you should read this: http://hixie.ch/advocacy/xhtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. Framesets are neither valid in HTML5 nor XHTML 1.1, but they will continue to work in major browsers for compatibility reasons. If you need to use a frameset and want your document to validate you need to pick a document type that includes them such as XHTML 1.0 Frameset.
3. There is just XHTML5, which is nothing more than HTML5 written like XHTML, complying with the syntax rules as given by XML. But as mentioned in the comments, unless you go out of your way to serve your pages as XHTML you are never really authoring or serving XHTML, so you may as well stick with the more permissive syntax rules that come with the HTML syntax of HTML5.

Comment: Why would you discourage someone to conform to the tightest syntax? I don't see anyone encouraging others to write `goto`s in their code saying using it is more permissive than not. Every other programmer is encouraged to stick to the strictest mode of interpretation, EXCEPT web frontend engineers. Its madness

Comment: @Milind R: If you're going to write all of your markup by hand, or at least have full control over any code that generates markup, and you don't need to support browsers that don't support the XHTML content-type to begin with (IE8 and older), you're more than welcome to use strict syntax. But not everyone has that luxury, especially when it comes to generated markup. If a third-party library spits markup that is not well-formed, good luck getting it to work with your site.

Comment: Aren't there libraries which convert malformed html to xhtml? And whose problem do you think is malformed html? In the rest of the programming world, it's still the author. Don't they manage somehow?

Answer (score 1):

There is XHTML5 (the XHTML syntax for HTML5). [Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-xhtml-syntax.html), [good blog post](https://blog.whatwg.org/xhtml5-in-a-nutshell), [another good blog post](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/xhtml5).

In essence, you can write HTML5 as if it was XHTML, by sticking to several rules.

Comment: If by "rules" you mean "restrictions", OK. Just keep in mind that HTML5 is better than XHTML5.

Comment: Agreed on both count, @MrLister, sir.

Comment: @MrLister Better how? all browsers have progressive rendering for XHTML, which removes one of the last reasons for using HTML over XHTML.

Comment: @MilindR my comment was not about HTML vs XHTML as such, but about the so-called "XHTML5", which has less functionality than HTML 5. (It doesn't have named entity references like `&nbsp;` and such.)